# Find anchor tag that contains specific text?

Tags: jquery

```
subMenu.find('a[href="#' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('active');
```

it will work if submenu contains:

```
<a href="#id">
```

How to make it work if I have something like:

```
<a href="/page#id">
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to target those `a` tags.

```
subMenu.find('a[href$="#' + this.id + '"]').addClass('active'); 
// -----------------^^----- here
```